# Bing api Advanced operator for web search using python

Tags: python, bing-api

I want to use an advanced operator to filter my search result. Search result should only contain PDF. I added the advanced operator (filetype: pdf). But seems it not working.

```
subscription_key = "My_ACCESS_KEY"
assert subscription_key
search_url = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search"
search_term = "NASA"
import requests

headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" : subscription_key}
params  = {"q": search_term, "filetype":"pdf", "responseFilter":"Webpages", textDecorations":True, "textFormat":"HTML"}
response = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers, params=params)
response.raise_for_status()
search_results = response.json()
```

I could not figure it how to use advanced operator (**filetype:pdf**) to filter search results.

Could anyone please suggestion me how to use it?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the example code from their documentation. I added the `filetype` as url query parameter and seems working.

```
import requests

subscription_key = "..."
assert subscription_key

search_url = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search"

search_term = "Machine%20Learning&filetype=pdf"

headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" : subscription_key}

params  = {"q": search_term}
response = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers, params=params)
response.raise_for_status()
search_results = response.json()

print(search_results)
```